# PHP include() some html code into a DOM object using html()

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have some inline jQuery mixed with PHP and i want to do something like this:

```
$("#someDiv").html("<?php include(page.php); ?>")
```

The problem is that ill get `"Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL"` errors due to new line characters and i think also double quote characters inside page.php.

My question is how can i go about doing an include() into a html() without worrying about illegal characters?

Thanls

Comment: Can't you just include inside `#someDiv`? Something like `<div id="someDiv"><?php include (page.php);?></div>`.

Comment: problem is that this code is in a partial view and  `someDiv` is located in another partial view

Comment: Have you tried using AJAX to call the page?

Comment: I can do that, but im trying a way without having to make the extra AJAX call

Comment: Is there a reason for this? I don't think using include() inside javascript/jquery code like this is a good idea really.

Comment: Im just trying to avoid the extra AJAX call. I know mixing PHP and javascript is not always the best idea but this is literally 1 line worth of code as compared to say 10 lines of code for the ajax call etc. If there is no easy way to do this, then doesnt matter. i was just curious

Comment: I'll add a fast method that jQuery has, which uses AJAX without having to use 10 lines. (As an answer, for the code)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to do this is using AJAX. jQuery has something implemented called $.get, as well as $.post (which you can use for post data). Since you just want to include, we can use $.get which is 2 lines of code.

```
$.get("page.php", function(data){
    $("#someDiv").html(data);
})
```

Define the page in the first parameter, then a callback function as the second parameter. The variable inside the callback function will be the data that is returned. Then inside the callback function, simply set the html of the desired div, and if you want to do some kind of success message with alert() too, that's always an option.

I hope this helps; you avoid the long winded AJAX method as well as the insecurity of include()-ing inside javascript.

Comment: This will suffice. Thank you